# How to iterate Json text in Python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to iterate below json content in python

Json file :

```
 {   "taskName":"ENG-12-2020-4-30-1200",
   "datasets":[      {
         "content":"How are you.",
         "isSave":False,
         "order":1,
         "transContent":"How are you."

},
      {
         "content":"How is your family.",
         "isSave":False,
         "order":2,
         "transContent":"How is your family."

},
      {
         "content":"How about your studies?.",
         "isSave":False,
         "order":3,
         "transContent":"How about your studies?"

},
      {
         "content":"How about your work.",
         "isSave":False,
         "order":4,
         "transContent":"How about your work."

},
```

Expected Output should provide after each "transContent" as below:
How are you
How about your studies?
How about your work.

I tried with the below code:

```
import json

with open('C:/Users/name/iterate-63.json') as f:
  data = json.load(f)
jsonnn_tree = objectpath.Tree(data['taskName'])
print(jsonn_tree)
```

I am unable to iterate the element that contains each ""transContent"

Someone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

First, your json appears to be invalid. If it is an actual json file `False` needs to be `false` and the single-quotes need to be double `'` to `"`.

data.json:

```
{
    "taskName": "ENG-12-2020-4-30-1200",
    "datasets": [
        {
            "content": "How are you.",
            "isSave": false,
            "order": 1,
            "transContent": "How are you."
        },
        {
            "content": "How is your family.",
            "isSave": false,
            "order": 2,
            "transContent": "How is your family."
        },
        {
            "content": "How about your studies?.",
            "isSave": false,
            "order": 3,
            "transContent": "How about your studies?"
        },
        {
            "content": "How about your work.",
            "isSave": false,
            "order": 4,
            "transContent": "How about your work."
        }
    ]
}
```

Simple code to load the json to a dictionary:

```py
import json

def open_json(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as file:
        return json.load(file)

data = open_json('./data.json')

print(data)
```

Output:

```py
{'taskName': 'ENG-12-2020-4-30-1200', 'datasets': [{'content': 'How are you.', 'isSave': False, 'order': 1, 'transContent': 'How are you.'}, {'content': 'How is your family.', 'isSave': False, 'order': 2, 'transContent': 'How is your family.'}, {'content': 'How about your studies?.', 'isSave': False, 'order': 3, 'transContent': 'How about your studies?'}, {'content': 'How about your work.', 'isSave': False, 'order': 4, 'transContent': 'How about your work.'}]}
```

You can now access the json data as a python dictionary:

```py
print(data['datasets'][0]['transContent'])
```

Output:

```
How are you.
```

Comment: Hello sankar. Thank you for your help on this. really appreciate